# Identifying a malloc'd object from Instruments

Tags: malloc, instruments

I'm running the Allocation tool in Xcode 4/Instruments, and would like to identify the class of a specific malloc'd object. I know the responsible caller, but can't figure out which specific object is being allocated - all I have is an address, a category of "malloc 712KB", as well as details on the responsible library and caller. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the extended detail view shows the call stack for the memory allocation. Looking at the call stack helps identify where in your code you allocated the memory, which would help you determine the class of the object that was allocated.

Choose View > Extended Detail View to show the extended detail view or click the right button in the View group in the toolbar.

Comment: I do this, but I just get hex addresses (like 0x164992), nothing useful. "Re-Symbolicate Document" in the File menu is dimmed out. How do I get something useful from this? Or can you not, for malloc?

Comment: Ahh, that target was set to build for "Release" instead of "Debug". Changing that setting turned the hex addresses into a useful stack trace. :-)